# Microsoft Access - Percentage from Grid

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have created a 15x15 grid of checkboxes in a form. Each checkbox is saved in the table tblDiscolourationGrid with the name being the reference ex: A1B1 etc...

Now I would like to workout the percentage of checked boxes ie: (count of checkboxes = True)/225 where 225 is (15x15) ie: the total number of checkboxes. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Count the checkboxes and those checked, like (air code):

```vb
Private Sub ButtonCheck_Click()

    Dim Control As Access.Control
    
    Dim Total   As Integer
    Dim Checked As Integer
    
    For Each Control In Me.Controls
        If Control.ControlType = acCheckBox Then
            Total = Total + 1
            Checked = Checked + Abs(Nz(Control.Value, False))
        End If
    Next
    
    Me!TotalCheckedCheckBoxes.Value = Checked / Total

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi first of all thank you for this...do you add this to a sub function...sorry for my naiveness but I am totally new to this

Comment: You could add to your form a button named _ButtonCheck_ and then assign the code to its _OnClick_ event. Also, add an unbound textbox named _TotalCheckedCheckBoxes_. See revised code, please.

Comment: Thanks a lot! By any chance is there a way that the textbox TotalCheckedCheckBoxes is automatically updated without the need of a button please?

Comment: Yes. One option is to call the code from the _AfterUpdate_ event of each checkbox. Another is to use the hidden gem of Access VBA: _WithEvents_. It takes initially a little more. You can find an introduction in my project [VBA.ModernTheme](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.ModernTheme) which has a link to an article by me.